# how to check how many checkboxes are checked if i don't know their id's

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have bunch of checkboxex generated from an php loop, and the code look like  this:

```
 if ($searchQuerySelectedRooms === FALSE) {
       $searchQuerySelectedRooms = array();
 }
 foreach ($rooms as $room) {
     if (in_array($room['roomID'], $searchQuerySelectedRooms)) {
         $checker = 'checked="checked"';
     } else {
         $checker = '';
     }
     echo '<input type="checkbox" id=box"'.$room['roomID'].'" name="rooms[]" value="' . $room['roomID'] . '" style="float:left;width:20px; margin-right:10px;" ' . $checker . ' class="box"/>';
```

Bellow of this loop, i want to find out which checkboxes are checked and to append some html of the div with class newprice.

I have searched on google, but all the examples starts use getElementById, which is useless in my case, since id's are build from the database, and I don't know which id's will be assigned to each checkbox.

Anyone know how can I do this?

Regards, John

Comment: Can you please post your HTML structure.

Comment: You could use jQuery .each() to check all checkboxes..

Comment: Try $('input:checkbox:checked') will give you all check checkboxes, But i suggest you to give a class and get it to isolate from other area where used

Comment: Hi Rory. Structure of the chceckbox which is the only relevant for the question is already posted. I have only php code on the page for the moment, nothing else, i will add the html later when I complete the code.

Comment: Are your ids valid? Remember they shouldn't start with number.

Comment: Hi Marek. My id's start with number right now, i will fix that now, thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all checkboxes have the class `box`, you can use:

```
// iterate over all checked checkboxes with class box
$('input.box[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Your answer did exactly what I wanted. Thanks man. I have to wait 5 minutes, and the I will be able to accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var amountChecked = $('input:checked');
```

Comment: This will also select the radio input field which is checked.

Comment: Oh right, true that. Well the other have corrected it already.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use document.getElementsByName() or you can apply one common class to all check box and use jquery like $('.class_name').
Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
var howMany = $('input:checked').length;
```

EDITED:

```
var howMany = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
```

Comment: This will also select the radio input field which is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/paBLJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you work with jQuery, it's really easy. You have special selectors for checkboxes like ´:checkbox´ or ´input[type=checkbox]´

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
   $(this).append('your html structure to append')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if(document.getElementsByTagName("input").type=="checkbox")
```

in javascript or you can use

```
$("input:checkbox")
```

in jquery.